# Why am I getting an error in derived transformation while validating datetime field?

Tags: ssis

I have a source with `0000-00-00` in a datetime field. When I try to copy that to an SQL destination the error pops up.

Im trying a derived column to fix it. When it's `0000-00-00` change it to `NULL`.
Here's the pic.

[image]

Why isn't it working? I've tried changing the `0000-00-00 00:00:00` to `0000-00-00` and still, it won't work.

Comment: Your 'Data Type' reads Timestamp, maybe it should be DateTime?

Comment: @MarcBernier Thanks for the tip. How can I change that? it won't let me clicking on it. Should I force it in the expression field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explanation:

Try the following expression to resolve the issue. Since your incoming field is of `DATETIME` data type and you want to ignore all the values that have zeroes in them. You can find the DAY of the given datetime value and check whether if it is zero or not. If it is zero, you need to use the NULL function `NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)` else you can simply use the field name, which contains the valid date and time value. Then, type cast the whole expression into data type `DT_DBTIMESTAMP`

#### Expression:

> (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(DAY([FechaHoraCorteAgente]) == 0 ?  NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) :  [FechaHoraCorteAgente])

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was it. and Thanks for the explanation, now I see why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You should use NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) instead of NULL in your expression.